# How to keep jailed users from changing directory to parent dirs?

Tags: ftp, jail, chroot

I've `chroot` users with

```
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

and I'm the only user in the `chroot_list` file. Other users log in jailed but when they go to the relative parent directory `..` they are able to move around the server. How do I make their home directory the parent most directory they can get to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
```

From the `man` page:

> **passwd_chroot_enable**
>
> If enabled, along with chroot_local_user , then a chroot() jail location may be specified on a per-user basis. Each user's jail is derived from their home directory string in /etc/passwd.